# How to know if MongoDb addToSet added or not?

Tags: mongodb

When I use `addToSet`, I need to know if the array was updated with the new element or not?
Does `addToSet` return a value that I can use to find this out?
If not, then what is the way to do this atomically?

Comment: The way to do it atomically? Don't use mongo.

Answer (score 0):

apparently this is a known issue with mongodb :(
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3409

Answer (score 0):

According to https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3409 mentioned in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20968815/963287), since MongoDB 2.5.5¹, and thus in all currently supported versions of MongoDB (4.2, 4.4, 5.x and 6.0), the way to tell if `$addToSet` actually added/changed the document is through the `modifiedCount` field of the return value.

Example:

```
> db.Group.updateOne({_id:ObjectId("620a8032a9529e01135225e4")}, {$addToSet: {users: '1'}})
{
  acknowledged: true,
  insertedId: null,
  matchedCount: 1,
  modifiedCount: 1,
  upsertedCount: 0
}
> db.Group.updateOne({_id:ObjectId("620a8032a9529e01135225e4")}, {$addToSet: {users: '1'}})
{
  acknowledged: true,
  insertedId: null,
  matchedCount: 1,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedCount: 0
}
```

Note that on the first run `modifiedCount: 1` (added), and then on the second run `modifiedCount: 0` (not added).

---

¹ a [development version](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/versioning/#historical-releases) before the [2.6 release](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/2.6/) from 2014